# Huge bundle file when adding pdfmake (and vfs fonts)

Tags: webpack-2, pdfmake

I use the excellent `pdfmake` JS library in my project, with webpack 2.2. However it makes the produced bundle much larger (at least + 1 MB *ouch*).

One problem is the big fonts file - I only use the default Roboto font, is there a way to get rid of the fonts file, then ? Why do we need this at all ? System fonts would be ok in my case.

Surprisingly it seems the total size of the files from a CDN is smaller than the resulting added size in my bundle... Maybe there is some special configuration to do in webpack for pdfmake ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you need to have a font in there. https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side if you add a smaller font file for your needs, it should go down a bit, but I don't think you can use system fonts with pdfmake.